# Wysiwyg profile returns empty input field

Tags: wysiwyg

I have the CKEditor Wysiwyg profile assigned to the plain text format. When I want to edit text somewhere in Full HTML, it works. But when I select the plain text, the input field of the text is completely gone.
Here are 2 images to help explain what happens.

First image is normal, second image is when I selected the plain text format and where I would like to see a wysiwyg editor appear.

[image: This is the normal input view]

[image: This is what happens when I select plain text]

Comment: First things first - why would you want a wysiwyg for the plain text format? That defeats it's purpose

Comment: You're right, plain text is badly chosen profile, but it's just to point out that it doesn't work. When assigned to Full HTML, it makes more sense, but doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite with you, the question says it works for full HTML but your comment suggests it doesn't?

Comment: No, it never works. First image is standard text format profile without wysiwyg. when i select a text format WITH wysiwyg, the input field dissapears, like in second image.

Comment: What if you assign the wysiwyg profile to FULL HTML text format and let the PLAIN TEXT text format without any wysiwyg? It would be more logical and maybe that's the point.

Comment: I did that and now the plain text works again and the full html doesn't work.. It's really in the wysiwyg editor that there's an error I guess